# How thick does the impermeable layer need to be when grading a yard?

Tags: soil, drainage, yard, grading, sand

I'm grading my yard and have found a deep layer of sand (at least 2 ft) extending out about 10ft. Perhaps the sub base for a patio? I understand I need an impermeable layer to ensure rain runs away from the house rather than draining downwards. I plan to use regular, fairly dense soil from elsewhere in the yard.

Considering that no soil is completely impermeable, how thick should I make my soil layer to be effective? Do I really need to test the permeability of my soil?? That seems like overkill...

Comment: Why do you think you need an impermeable layer of soil around your house?

Comment: I have never heard of this.  Infact, the opposite is true for downunder.  There are regulations on maximum percentage of your property that can be impervious.

Comment: My understanding is that you want to direct water as far away from your foundation as possible. Isn't that why grading a yard is important? If you have permeable material by your house, why bother grading?

Comment: @Tenz Water will flow away from your home underground as well.  Here's a cool diagram https://www.unomaha.edu/international-studies-and-programs/center-for-afghanistan-studies/academics/transboundary-water-research/DLM15/GW5.jpg

Comment: Thanks @MackM. The thing is I have sand going down a long way, so I don't know what the slope is below that. If the impermeable material under the sand slopes towards the house, that's bad news. That's why I'd like to grade above the sand.

Comment: @Tenz I see what you're saying, I have an area in my yard where the top of a heavy clay hill was 'leveled' with top soil. The former low areas were muddy messes after a rain, basically subsurface puddles. That said, it did always drain eventually.  I've never heard of any issues with subsurface layers channeling water back towards a structure but I don't disbelieve.

Comment: I've also never heard of adding an impermeable layer to help with runoff, just regrading. I assumed that was because the subsurface water movement would saturate the covered area anyway and regrading changes the hydraulic pressure differential underground, but I really don't know.  Definitely out of my depth :)

Comment: Thanks for the input anyway @MackM. I maybe overthinking this and just ensure there's a slope and be done with it!

Comment: @Tenz Maybe it's too basic for them, but I see the Earth Science stack exchange site has a Hydrology tag. Maybe they'll have a better answer? https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrology